# How to use dedicated GPU over Thunderbolt

Tags: terminal, gpu, compatibility, thunderbolt

My goal is to have the noisy machine in another room, while having my peripherals, well, here.

I already got myself a [CalDigit TS4](https://www.caldigit.com/thunderbolt-station-4/) that would serve as a terminal for my peripherals, including displays, I got a [15m Thunderbolt cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08CK31Z88), but now, as I'm looking for a motherboard with a [Thunderbolt interface](https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/proart/proart-z790-creator-wifi/techspec/), I'm having hard time understanding what GPU is going to be utilized for the video signal through the said thunderbolt connection. Will it be the internal GPU of the CPU, or the [dedicated GPU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BGV6LQYR) connected to the motherboard.

I would like some sort of confirmation that what I've imagined here will actually work. That the dedicated GPU will be used as a display signal over the Thunderbolt connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1700/ProArt_Z790-CREATOR_WIFI/E20704_ProArt_Z790-CREATOR_WIFI_UM_WEB.pdf?model=ProArt%20Z790-CREATOR%20WIFI) fully and explicitly answers all your questions:

- The upper USB-C port is flexible and will either use the CPU-integrated GPU (if present) or DisplayPort-In 1
- The lower USB-C port is hardwired to DisplayPort-In connector 2
- To use your dedicated GPU, you must connect one or two of its DisplayPort outputs to the DisplayPort-In connectors on your mainboard

Be aware: If the mainboard does not have a DisplayPort-In system like this one, your dedicated GPU will not be used for Thunderbolt/DP Alt Mode!

Answer (score -1):

I had the very same need and based on some posts on reddit, I enabled iGPU on ASRock Z790 ITX/TB4 (iGPU multimonitor in BIOS) and ran TB output to a DELL U4025QW display.  While the connection itself is controlled by iGPU, on Windows 11 23H2 the nVidia is doing the majority of the work as seen in Task Manager.  I am not sure exactly what's happening here.  Might be worth a try for anyone else facing the same challenge.

Also another hardware solution if you don't need actual Thunderbolt protocol but can live with DP Alt mode over USB-C to achieve a single cable solution is a powered DisplayPort to USB-C cable like this [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0BKG23KTK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BKG23KTK).  This may not be relevant to OP's question centered around a 15 meter TB cable, which by requirement must be active but might work for people with less stringent requirements.